# How to FIND ALL available ubuntu openssl versions?

Tags: apt, ssl, openssl

Usual version mismatch problem.

I need a simple terse answer to the question of how to see all available versions.

sudo apt search libssl3

shows only one version.

Ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only 1 version per Ubuntu version.

If you want a list of versions for all current releases use [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libssl3&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)